# add external file to test run in mtm

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, tfs, automated-tests

I'm using TFS and MTM to run my automated tests and I'm wondering how can I attach a external file to the test run result?
At the end of every one of my tests I want my external reports files (they are generated during the tests in a known path) to be add to the test run result so I could access them via the MTM and I don't seem to find the option to do it. Can anyone help out?

Answer (score 0):

In the result history section of your test case you will see all your test results. Double click on any of the test result and it should open it. There is an attachment section in there with an "Add" button. You can use that to upload any files. 
It will have metadata, system info and action log file added for the test run.